# Отказ операции new

Tags: отладка, runtime, c++, visual-studio

Доброго времени суток. У меня стоит VS2008, и когда в debug-версии при отказе операции new bad_alloc не ловится, выводится или "This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way. Please contact the application's support team for more information." (прямо в консоли), либо появляется окно Debug Library. От чего здесь зависит выбор, в каком виде показывается ошибка? И можно ли сделать так, чтобы в консоль отладочная информация не писалась, а показывалось только окно?

Comment: Покажи код, так непонятно